# When your boss is trying to turn your co-workers against you

Tags: management, human-resources

Myself and my co-workers have recently uncovered that our boss is saying untruths and very unfair and negative things about performance at work and even peoples  personal situations.

Making up complete fabrications, if someone say's they are sick to the office manager, we have found emails to the office manager saying I bet they weren't sick I bet they were just hungover. He's always out on a Sat night!! Or she has not been staying late and she's a lazy bi*ch because she leaves on time.

There are many other things including telling complete lies to one person about another co-worker and then another completely separate lie to another co-worker.

What he doesn't realize is that we are all friends in the office as well as co-workers, and have slowly talked amoungst ourselves and realized what he has been doing.

I have now actually resigned due to this situation as I feel I cannot work for someone who is like this. He did not take the resignation that well but wished me well. I told him I was leaving due to a better career opportunity for me. He has then gone onto to say to the rest of the team in separate texts to them (after saying to me please don't tell the team I want to manage it) that I am leaving due to the fact I couldn't handle the role anymore and that she was under performing, he said that the girl I work alongside has had to pick up all my mistakes and slack over the last months and she came to him and said she was over it.

This is completely untrue and the girl I work with is very upset that he would implicate her into this saying that she has said those things. This is all after I have hit may target and made commission the last 2 months and he had told the team how great I was doing and that he was going to give me some extra clients.

I would like to bring to his attention that I am aware of all of this but I don't want to make thing terrible for the people still here after I leave even though we all know what's going on. I believe he needs to know we all know what he is doing. We do not have any sort of HR here so I guess that's why he gets away with it. Oh I forgot to mention the office manager also resigned 2 weeks before me as he was over dealing with this sort of behavior from our boss.

Comment: RANT.  Move on dude.   If your co-workers realize what he is doing they will realize realize what he is doing.

Comment: As the question stands, it's difficult to see what you are actually asking.  If you have a _specific_ question (however advice on what you should do is off-topic), then please try to rephrase (and reformat from one big wall of text :) ) your question so we can best help you :)

Comment: My question is should I tell him I know everything he has said or leave it?

Comment: You don't know everything he has said and he does not care what you know.  Move on.

Answer (score 4):

If you have resigned, thank him for his time and move on.  It won't help you or any of your co-workers to say anything.  It is up to them to handle the situation for themselves if they have issues with your boss.

It's been noted here many times that leaving with a rant does you no favours and won't change anything anyway.  Be the professional one, walk away and enjoy your new role :)

Comment: ..and if you get wind of any job opportunities that would suit your friends still working for this boss, pass them on! It sounds like they would appreciate them.